# option -f for linux command

Tags: linux, arguments, uniq

this is the content of test file:

```
this this  
this that  
is that  
a that  
MAP that  
map that
```

when I do `uniq testCase -f1`, the result is:

```
this this  
this that
```

which is reasonable, but if I run: `testCase -f2`, I get:

```
this this
```

why is this happening? and can someone tell me what is the default delimiter of -f, it is not in man.

Comment: What did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: "Delimiter", not "deliminator".

Answer (score 5):

From `man uniq`:

> A field is a run of blanks (usually spaces and/or TABs), then non-blank characters.  Fields are skipped before chars.

With `-f2` you're skipping all your fields, so only the first line gets output, all the others are equal after the second field (none have more than two).

Comment: should be accepted.